# Why do TINA-TI don't have any library/ spice model for transformer which have auxiliary winding?

Tags: simulation

I want to perform simulation of flyback converter design (110Vdc to 5Vdc,2A) .In the schematic there is need of one [transformer(**T1**)](https://1fichier.com/?e6yg79v7tw) which has an auxiliary winding required to give supply to PWM  switching controller [ucc28c40](http://www.ti.com/product/UCC28C40) . While drawing circuit on TINA-TI's editor ,I didn't find required transformer nor any library file for it.

So where do I get Pspice model library file for transformer which has auxiliary winding that can be used in TINA-TI Simulation software? 
[image]

Comment: No luck with your original LTspice simulation?

Comment: It's not a buck converter, it's a flyback converter.

Comment: @winny yes, I tried but couldn't get  successful in LTSpice simulation . I am hoping that I will get simulation results as design obtained from webench and simulator I am using now is TINA both are of Texas instrument,

Comment: You idea that the Texas parts will simulate better in TINA is sound but your transformer on the other hand will be more difficult there.

Comment: @winny yes ,in LTSpice I created that transformer  from 3 inductor coils but here in TINA ,  I don't  find any  such option.

Comment: @user3559780 You're still at this? Didn't you say you actually want a charger for smartphones, or did I misunderstood?

Comment: You will most likley be better off making your LTspice simulation work.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer given by TINA-TI support team is

You have 2 options:

(1) ON the top bar, go to Basic >> Select "Transformers" >> Select "Nonlinear transformer with separate secondary coils". When you add this, you can customize the parameters as needed.

(2) If you have the transformer model from a manufacturer, you can import that into TINA-TI. Instructions can be found here (Check out Training 1.9):

[training.ti.com/tina-ti-video-training-series](https://training.ti.com/tina-ti-video-training-series)